# How to make asp.net page responde in XML format

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, header

I want to make `asp.net` page to respond in `xml` format. I don't want to `xmlWriter` class.
How to set the the header for the response type as xml foramt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your codebehind inside Page_Load:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

But it is not best practice. Please consider using in you aspx file in Page directive:

```
ContentType="text/xml"
```

You can start your implementation using example from [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/how-to-build-an-rss-feed-with-asp-net/) RSS tutorial. Remember to strip  output rendered by asp.net out of illegal characters like '&' etc...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use contenttype = "text/xml", you can refer to below link

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_contenttype.asp